# Trying to create a pivot table, runtime error 91

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, runtime

Trying to name a range "PK" and create a pivot table with that range. When I run this code I get runtime error 91. The code previous to this bit creates a new workbook from a template so all of the tabs are pre-set if that makes sense.

Creates dynamic range to use for the pivot table

```vb
Dim pkrange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Lastcol As Long
Dim pksheet As Worksheet
Dim startcell As Range
Dim pk As String

Set pksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Last PK Data")
Set startcell = pksheet.Range("A1")

LastRow = pksheet.Cells(pksheet.Rows.Count, startcell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
Lastcol = pksheet.Cells(startcell.Row, pksheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set pkrange = Range(startcell, pksheet.Cells(LastRow, Lastcol))

pk = "PK"
pksheet.Names.Add Name:=pk, RefersTo:=pkrange
```

Sets pivot table

```vb
Dim PKpvtable As PivotTable
Dim PKpvCache As PivotCache
Dim PKstartPvt As String
Dim PKsrcData As String

PKsrcData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Last PK Data").Range("PK").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
PKstartPvt = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot table").Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

Set PKpvCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, PKsrcData)

Set PKpvtable = PKpvCache.CreatePivotTable(PKstartPvt, "PivotTable1")
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: LastRow = pksheet.Cells(pksheet.Rows.Count, startcell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Did you include all your code? Do you do anything to `pksheet` or `startcell` before that line (delete cells, for example)?

Comment: Not at all. The code before that doesn't use any of those variables.

Comment: I can't repro the error. Maybe add a `Debug.Print pksheet.Name` or `Debug.Print startcell.Address` and see which throws an error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code works perfect for me. Maybe the code before this part is not written properly (you have a `With` without `End With` or something like that? Can you check it out?

Comment: I don't have anything like the sorts unfortunately. I am a noob and try to keep it as trashy and simple as possible. And thank you for the help and the welcome.

Comment: Could it be I am not selecting some library or similar?